# How can I send PDF file from my angular fronted to my laravel backend

Tags: angular, laravel, jspdf

I'm trying to send a PDF file created in angular, By the jsPDF plugin to my laravel backend. 
I tried getting the base64 datauristring. And sent it to the backend. Then I used the base64 decode and wrote it to storage. But I was unable to get the exact PDF file there was an error saying the file is broken .

Comment: Can you post you code?