# Convert website form to PDF and email to webmaster

Tags: php, jquery, email

I am trying to create a form for my website which once submitted will be converted to PDF and them emailed to myself (webmaster).

I appreciate that I cannot complete the action purely with JQuery/Javascript, I will need to use PHP to send the email.

The Javascript to convert the HTML to PDF

```
var doc = new jsPDF(); 
var specialElementHandlers = { 
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) { 
        return true; 
    } 
};
$('#submitformz').click(function () { 
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, { 
        'width': 190, 
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers 
    }); 
    doc.save('sample-page.pdf');  
});
```

The problem I have with the above is that it converts to PDF and then downloads on the users computer.
Ideally I would like to convert the 'doc.save' so that it ties in with the PHP to email the document

the PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "webmaster@website.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}


$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
} 

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Or... Is there any way that I could ammend the Javascript so that instead of the file downloading on the customers computer, that it, instead, downloads into the media library on my websites backend?

Comment: If you want the pdf to be sent via email then you would have to create the pdf on server with php and attach with email. You cannot use client-side (javascript) pdf converter because it will just print the area as a pdf and download on user's computer. Look for server-side (php) pdf converter/creator.

Comment: Well, you can certainly convert the html to pdf from client side using jspdf and then send it to the server via ajax or similar. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497867/4271117f).

Comment: Or this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489788/how-can-i-send-pdf-file-from-my-angular-fronted-to-my-laravel-backend/54499797#54499797)

Comment: Its a bad idea to allow arbitrary files to be sent to you from a trusted source, you should definitely do it on the server. Though looking your code, why bother, just send the text, looks like html, so convert it or wrap it in a pre tag. You might also want to look into not using mail() and use a lib which handles HTML and header injection shinanigans for you.

Comment: @LawrenceCheroneyou will need to excuse my naievity here. I am relatively new to coding and learning this as I go so am a bit unsure as to what wrapping in pre tag means... also... Is it not possible to convert the html to PDF via JS and then send to me as an attachment via PDF? ideally, once the person clicks send, that would be what I would like to do

Answer (score 2):

If I`ve understood you currently, you should get data from client and front then in back-end with php create PDF (you can use wkhtmltopdf to convert a HTML(generated by data in back-end) to PDF) then send this PDF file by email.

Comment: Looks like a great solution. Excuse my naivety, I had meant to say in the question that I am using Wordpress on a shared hosting package but by the looks of the docs and tutorials I have looked at, this needs to be installed directly on the server?

Comment: Yes, it is. You have to install wkhtmltopdf software on your server.

Comment: I am unable to do that I have found out from speaking with my hosting provider as I am on a shared hosting package with no access to the server. Are there any solutions that you know of where I can create a PHP file which will allow a similar outcome?

Comment: Yes it is, you can use api of online pdf converter such as zamzar.com. You should send your html,image,word, ... file to this site by curl and it return a url to your callback  for download converted file.